# Generating a LOG file for windows application

Tags: c#

I have a windows application where I do have some functionalities like Find and Replace, changing the date formats and so on.

By generating the LOG file, I would like to trace the modifications done to the file in my windows application.

Can anyone help me achieving this?

Comment: What is the actual question? How to write to a log file? Try one of the many logging libraries like NLog, log4net etc. How to track changes made by commands in your application? Write to the log when the command starts and completes. Something else? Please make a concrete question

Comment: Try looking here: [How to do logging in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057567/how-to-do-logging-in-c)

Comment: I want to track the changes of the file in my application.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to Log actions performed by application you can write them to an external file.

```
private void Log(string text, bool LineBreak)
    {
        try
        {
            if (LineBreak)
            {
                File.AppendAllText("LogFile.txt", System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
            File.AppendAllText("LogFile.txt", System.Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + ":- " + text);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Log exceptions like this:

```
private void LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            File.AppendAllText("LogFile.txt", System.Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + ":- Main Exception:");
            File.AppendAllText("LogFile.txt", System.Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            File.AppendAllText("LogFile.txt", System.Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);

            File.AppendAllText("LogFile.txt", System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + "Inner Exception:");
            File.AppendAllText("LogFile.txt", System.Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException.Message);
            File.AppendAllText("LogFile.txt", System.Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what's the assembly need to be added for ServiceLogFilePath?

Comment: @user1191818 "ServiceLogFilePath" is a variable contain log file path . see i have edited  code spinet for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to do some logging to the trace output via

```
Trace.WriteLine("Some message");
```

and hook up a trace listener, which implements

```
TraceListener
```

or use a predifined listener. A comprehensive tutorial can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/sk36c28t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).