# Writing to a text file(log file) on remote server in c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, winforms-to-web

My intention is create a log file on a remote server from a standalone app(Winforms). Also, will require to edit/read it at times from the application.
Please provide your expert advice and insights.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do logging in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057567/how-to-do-logging-in-c)

Comment: Thanks Jake. However, what I'm looking for is not logging in local environment but logging on a remote server.

Comment: So from the point of view of the remote server, you can still log locally, meaning writing to a log on a remote server. Are you trying to log to a second location, meaning not on the remote server?

Comment: I'm just trying to log on a remote server from a stand alone app running locally at end user's side.