# How can I load multiple images using LoadAsync() in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I'm trying to update the GUI, and I have an asynchronous function that uses LoadAsyc(), when I load just one image, it works but when I try to load more than one, the second one doesn't display.

This my code:

```
public UserFriendlyInterface()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    locationFileH5 = "";
    serverStatus = false;
    ipAddress = getLocalIPAddress();
    port = 5000;
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"flask_server\cnn\_prepImages_");
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
}

private void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    updateImages();
}

async Task updateImages()
{
    pictureBoxNormalImg.WaitOnLoad = false;
    pictureBoxNormalImg.LoadAsync(@"flask_server\cnn\_prepImages_\normal.jpg");

    pictureBoxSegmentation.WaitOnLoad = false;
    pictureBoxSegmentation.LoadAsync(@"flask_server\cnn\_prepImages_\segmentation.jpg");
}
```

Comment: you will have to await the async call

Comment: Please, can you tell how and where I should put it?

Comment: So if you comment out the first load, does the second image work?

Comment: It's going to work, however, I need to display both.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Your code works fine here. Most likely your 2nd path is wrong.

Comment: About the files "normal.jpg" and "segmentation.jpg", how are they changed? Depending on the way you change these files, the [`FileSystemWatcher.Changed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed) event will be raised one or two times for each file. So the `UpdateImages` method could be called 4 times per operation, and some of them could be while one of the files is updated. So there are a lot of possible reasons why this code may behave in unpredictable ways.

Comment: There is no filter and so no image needs to be changed. It is enough to change, add or delete any file in the folder.

Comment: The folder that contains those two images, it's being updated by overwriting the images, then I want to delete the previous images & display the new ones, when the directory changes.

Comment: @VictorBryant what should happen if only one image in the folder is overwritten, and the other is not? What if both are overwritten, but with a delay of 10 seconds between the first and the second?

Comment: Good question! I'm sure that all of them are overwritten, but maybe one of them with a delay of microseconds. Then, I could use Task.Delay before updating the GUI.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Theodor Zoulias. I just added the Task.Delay() on the first line of the updateImage() function with a delay of 700, and it works. You were right, I had to wait until the whole directory has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be achieved more robustly by querying the `Name` property of the [`FileSystemEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemeventargs) object, and updating only the corresponding `PictureBox`.

```
private static void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox;
    switch (e.Name.ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        case "normal.jpg": pictureBox = pictureBoxNormalImg; break;
        case "segmentation.jpg": pictureBox = pictureBoxSegmentation; break;
        default: pictureBox = null; break;
    }
    if (pictureBox != null)
    {
        Image image = null;
        try
        {
            using (var temp = new Bitmap(e.FullPath))
            {
                image = new Bitmap(temp);
            }
        }
        catch { } // Swallow exception
        if (image != null)
        {
            pictureBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate ()
            {
                pictureBox.Image = image;
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

I would avoid the [`LoadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadasync) method because it is intended mainly for loading images from the internet, and because [I don't totally trust it](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/155784.aspx).

---

**Update:** There were two problems with my initial code:
1) [Free file locked by new Bitmap(filePath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803935/free-file-locked-by-new-bitmapfilepath)
2) [FileSystemWatcher Changed event is raised twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice)

The updated code solves these problems (hopefully), but not in the most robust or efficient way possible.

---

**Update:** To make the code more efficient, by avoiding the repeated loading of the images caused by multiple firings of the `Changed` event, you could use the extension method `OnChanged` found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice/58079327#58079327). It suffices to replace the line below:

```
watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;
```

...with this one:

```
watcher.OnChanged(Watcher_Changed, 100);
```

Comment: I have two pictures boxes on a form, but I can guarantee that both images get to the file almost at the same time, just with a delay of microseconds, that's why I'm using Task.Delay() at the top of the updateImage() function.

Comment: I just tested your code and when I try for the second time. It doesn't display the new image, it keeps the first image.

Comment: I updated my answer. You should consider adding [logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057567/how-do-i-do-logging-in-c-sharp-without-using-3rd-party-libraries) to your application, so that you can log the exceptions. It helps with debugging too!